# Find the smallest interval

Tags: probability

Suppose that the continuous random variable X has cumulative distribution function given by 
$$ F(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{if }x<\sqrt2\\ x^2-2 &\text{if }\sqrt2\leq x\leq\sqrt3 \\1 &\text{if } x\geq\sqrt3\end{cases}$$Find the smallest interval [a,b] such that of $P(a\leq x\leq b) = 1.$

So, from definition of the probability density function we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1. $$Now we  need to find a smaller interval. I kinda guess that it's $[\sqrt2;\sqrt3]$, but I don't know how to prove that its the smallest. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Try to prove that if any inner point of $[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ is missing from such an interval, the probability can't be 1.

Comment: @Ingix, don't know if I'm thinking in the right direction, but here is what I came up with: We'll try to prove that if any inner point of $[\sqrt2;\sqrt3]$ is missing from such an interval, the probability can't be 1.Suppose there is a discontinuity in $[\sqrt2;\sqrt3]$, then we have $$\int_{\sqrt2}^{a-\epsilon}2xdx +\int_{a+\epsilon}^{\sqrt3}2xdx=1-4a\epsilon.$$ We need this integral to be equal to 1, so $1-4a\epsilon=1$ For a fixed a we get $\epsilon = 0$, hence there cant be any discontinuity in $[\sqrt2;\sqrt3]$, and this interval is smallest. Is it correct?

Comment: Are there any ways to solve this using only cumulative distribution function instead of density function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt$ and $P(a \le x \le b) = F(b) - F(a)$. You already know what $F(x)$ is, and it is all you need to calculate probability. There is no need to deal with $f(x)$.

If $a < \sqrt{2}$ or $b > \sqrt{3}$, then obviously the interval can be be shrunk without decreasing the probability. But for $a > \sqrt{2}, F(a) > 0$ and for $b < \sqrt{3}, F(b) < 1$. Therefore if either of those is true, then $P = F(b) - F(a) < 1$.